# ivy: prevent downloading sources and .txt files

Tags: ivy

How to tell IVY to not download source and .txt files. I have a dependency and it downloads license.txt files with it, when i use soemthing like this

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy-src-classpath" conf="compile"/>
```

it put the .txt files in the classpath which errors out while using java task

```
Unable to obtain resource from /home/muthiah/Work/ivy/cache/org.apache.commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging/licenses/license-1.1.1.txt: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **ivy.xml** file add a configuration mapping to the other module's "default" configuration:

```
<dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.5" conf="compile->default"/>
```

Without this mapping you're retrieving both the default and optional dependencies of the remote module.

Another good mapping (for Maven modules) to use is:

```
conf="compile->master"
```

This will retrieve the remote artifact without it's transient dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with multiple **java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file** in my ANT output logs, because there were licence .txt files in the classpath. The solution for me was to update the ivy:cachepath entry by adding **type="jar"**:

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy-src-classpath" conf="compile" type="jar"/>
```

This will restrict only jar files to be added to the classpath.