# Avoid javadoc and sources downloading, when using Maven ant Tasks

Tags: maven-2, ant, maven-ant-tasks

I'm developing with Maven Ant Tasks support. When asking the repository to download desired libraries, it also downloads javadoc and source for each library. Is there a way to only download library jars?

Actual build.xml:

```
<artifact:dependencies settingsFile="${maven.settingsFile}" pomRefId="projectPom"
                       filesetId="dependency.fileset"
                       sourcesFilesetId="sources.dependency.fileset"
                       javadocFilesetId="javadoc.dependency.fileset"
                       versionsId="dependency.versions">
        <remoteRepository refid="remote.repository" />
</artifact:dependencies>
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know the *src* and *javadoc* downloads are **off** by default. There should be an option in your IDE or whatever tool you use for Maven.

Are your working with Eclipse?
In Eclipse you can find the option here:

```
Window > Preferences  > Maven
```

Then tick the checkboxes (or rather untick them) 'Download Artifact Sources/JavaDoc'.

Comment: I have not Maven plugin installed in Eclipse 'cause I'm working with Maven Ant tasks plugin. Using Maven ant tasks I can take benefit of using Ant and Maven dependencies management.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. Most open source Maven modules don't have source and javadoc on the default "compile" Maven scope. Have you tried specifying a scope?

```
<artifact:dependencies filesetId="dependency.fileset" useScope="compile">
..
```

Alternatively you can also specify a "scope" attribute on each dependency.

Personally I use the [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) plugin for my Maven downloads. The same problem is solved by specifying the "default" or "compile" configuration mapping: [ivy: prevent downloading sources and .txt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654498/ivy-prevent-downloading-sources-and-txt-files/3662697#3662697)

Comment: does not work. Before using Maven Ant tasks, I tried including Ivy on my project, but it's been imposible to tune it (imho, too hard to just take benefit of dependency management)

Comment: That's a pity, sorry I couldn't be any more help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved: just remove sourcesFilesetId and javadocFilesetId attributes if you don't need sources and javadoc jar libraries.